# How can I make this span visible but not clickable/not interact with anything?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a span inside a div overlaid on a Mapbox instance. This looks as intended, however it can block the user from moving the map around. See this image below where everything in the red box is preventing the user from selecting the map to move it :

[image]

I did some digging and found the `pointer-events: none;` attribute, but this seems to do nothing. Here is my actual code for the span :

```
<div id="overlays" style="z-index: 999;visibility:visible;position:absolute;right: 6px;bottom : 35px;text-align:right;color:#ffffff;"><span id="panel_overlayFirst" style="text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;pointer-events: none;"></span></div>
```

This works as intended except it still prevents the user from being able to click the map where the text it. Is there even a solution for something like this? It doesn't seem like a big issue but when the user is working with smaller maps, this is causing trouble.

Comment: Seems it might be the `div` that's capturing the events. Try moving the `pointer-events: none` rule to the `div` style rather than the `span`.

Comment: Yes! Feel free to make that as an answer for credit.

Answer (score -1):

Use `pointer-events: none` on the `#overlays` div. `pointer-events` is an inherited property, so you don't need to additionally set it on any of the child elements of the div, unless you also override the inherited value in a child element, and want a child of the overridden-value child element to have no pointer events.

The issue with what you did (I'm pretty sure) is that you set it on the child of the overlay div instead of on the overlay div. If you only set it on the child, the child will no longer receive pointer events, but the parent (`div#overlays`) still will.

I'm pretty sure you can also manually propagate events to various elements (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). For example, you could put an event listener on the overlays div that conditionally passes the event on to the elements behind it if you still want the overlays to receive events under some conditions, but things might get weird with the `target` property of the event object.

Comment: Sorry for "stealing" this answer post from @motto, but you'll have to take my word for it that I didn't actually see their comment before writing this. I wrote it independently from their comment.